# Is there a way to send an image from an ajax to flask?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, multipartform-data

I've tried a few things but the only answers I can find are from 2013. I've seen some people say it only worked on 1.6 Jquery but im not sure

## Tried

```
<div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center p-2 w-100" class="create-post-forms">
            

            <fieldset>
              <label id="add_photo_button" for="uploadImage" class="w-50 me-1"> <div class="btn btn-primary w-100 border-0 ">Add Photo</div> </label>
              <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="postphoto" style="display: none">
          </fieldset>

</form>
```

## Javascript / Ajax

var photo = new FormData($('#post_info')[0]);

console.log(photo)

```
( ive also tried photo.get("myPhoto))


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/make_post_ajax",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({ myPhoto : photo,}),
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
  }
});
```

## Flask

```
    photo = request.files.get('myPhoto')
```

## And the Result is:

```
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide whether you want to send form data or JSON. A combination of both fails.

The following example shows you how to send the entire form to the server via AJAX. Please note that the content type is not set and the data is not processed. Only then will the form be sent in 'multipart/form-data' format, as is necessary for uploading a file.

```html
<form name="my-form">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="upload-image">Add Photo</label>
        <input type="file" id="upload-image" name="my-photo" />
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/make_post_ajax',
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        }).done(function() {
            console.log('Successful uploaded photo.');
        });
    })
});
```

```py
@app.post('/make_post_ajax')
def upload():
    file = request.files.get('my-photo')
    if file:
        print(file)
        return ''
    abort(400)
```

If you want to use JSON, I recommend converting the image data into a Base64 string before sending it.

Comment: i love you. have my children thank u. idk how i missed that